# What is the best way to set some attributes of Profile model is public(visible) or private(invisible) to other user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization

I have a Profile model and it has many attributes like email, image, age, address etc.
A end user can make some attributes private so that other users are not able to view that.
I solved this issue by adding a column to table `private_attr` and serialized it to store a hash like:-

```
{email: true, address: true, age: false }
```

Here attributes as key having value `true` are considered as private and not shown to the user other than to whom these belongs.

I want to know is this the best way to solve this problem, or there is any other way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can serialize just the fields that the user want to be private in an array(instead of a hash). Like `[:email, :address]` (using your example)

Then, when you will render the view, just check if the field is present in that column. Something like

```
<%= user.email unless user.private_fields.include?(:email) %>
```

You can even extract that logic to a view helper to avoid duplication.

```
<%= show_if_allowed(user, :email) %>
```

Then create a helper like this

```
def show_if_allowed(user, field)
    user[field] unless user.private_fields.include?(field)
end
```

Comment: Combined with the Presenter Pattern (class instanciated on the view, having methods about how to display attributes, etc), this would be - In my opinion - the best way. +1

Comment: @MrYoshiji then please add you answer too.

Comment: @SachinSingh instead of putting the show_if_allowed method in a helper, you put it in a presenter, like this http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-09-09-better-ruby-presenters

Answer (score 3):

Actually, that's what I would do if I had to deal with 8 to 10 attributes. But, if you have way too many attributes for your `Profile` model class and have complex logic of showing these attributes on the basis of user's group, public, shared, etc. then I'd encourage you to move this to either a separate model class, let's say: "`ProfileConfiguration` or `ProfileSetting`", which will maintain each attribute on a row level, or you can move these settings to Redis, where the structure will be like: `user_id: {attribute_name: true, type: 'type_name'}` but then there's a drawback that you'll be depending on Redis server's availability.

Now, in your case:

```
serialize :profile_preferences, Hash
```

and then you maintain it with(as you mentioned, just in the opposite manner for their assignment):

```
{email: false, address: false, age: true }
```

However, you can go ahead and create some handy methods you can call on your profile object:

```
after_initialize :load_profile_preferences

private

def load_profile_preferences
  profile_preferences.each do |attr, value|
    self.class.send(:define_method, "show_#{attr.to_s}?") { value }
  end
end
```

Now, you get handy methods like: `show_email?`, `show_address?`, and `show_age?` on `Profile` class's object which you can [delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) to `User` class instance. So, you can now do something like this in your views, for example:

```
<%= "Email: {user.email}" if user.show_email? %>
<%= "Address: {user.address}" if user.show_address? %>
<%= "Age: {user.age}" if user.show_age? %>
```

Comment: thanks, i am interested to know to more about the first approach i.e. using `ProfileConfiguration` model, could you elaborate that one, how to manage multiple users attributes with that.

Comment: Sure, I'd happy to put it in detail, please allow me some time.

Answer (score 2):

You asked if there were other ways. Sure. Whether one is better is up to you.

**Lots of Columns**

You could create additional columns for each attribute. email_protected: true/false (etc). If you only have 3 columns, that's not too bad but wouldn't scale well if you are protecting lots of attributes.

**Many to Many relationship**

You could have an additional model, such as ProtectedAttribute. A Profile has_many ProtectedAttributes and store the data in separate tables instead of serializing. This eliminates the serialized data into a single column.

**Additional Details follow as requested**

```
# I'm using User instead of Profile as Profile is a protected word in Rails
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_protected_attributes
  has_many :protected_attributes, through: :profile_protected_attributes

  def protect_attribute?(name)
    protected_attributes.where(name: name).present?
  end

  def show_attribute?(name)
    !protect_attribute(name)
  end

  def protect_attribute(name)
    return if self.protect_attribute?(name)
    protected_attributes << ProtectedAttribute.find_by_name(name)
  end

  def unprotect_attribute(name)
    protected_attributes.delete(ProtectedAttribute.find_by_name(name))
  end
end

class ProtectedAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_protected_attributes
  has_many :users, through: :profile_protected_attributes
end

# The join model
class ProfileProtectedAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :protected_attribute
end
```

The migrations (you'll need to tweak if you stick with Profile):

```
class CreateProtectedAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :protected_attributes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProfileProtectedAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :profile_protected_attributes do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :protected_attribute_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: could you explain the possible solution with `ProtectedAttribute` model?

Comment: Sure. I'll update my answer when I have time to write up the details.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the Class relationships and some sample helper methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a gem named [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to handle the rights your different kind of users you define in a ruby file (`ability.rb`). Then, I suggest you to have may be different serializer for one resource, each serializer dedicated to a specific user role, it's easy to do with [active-model-serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers).